# Light Javascript framework

Tags: frameworks, javascript, javascript-framework

I'm trying to create a small Javascript "framework" that I can use in my greasemonkey scripts. I only need **very** basic functions, so this is why I choose not to use mooTools or DOMAssistant. Besides, I'm not going to be silly and put DOMAssitant in a 20KB Greasemonkey script! I just want a small, neat snippet of code.

I have a small problem with the below code. I think its because I am returning an array in $() so I get .setStyle is not a function error message.

```
var fmini = {  
  $ : function(a) {
    var i=0,obj,d;
    var e = [];

    while (obj = arguments[i++]) {
      d = document.getElementById(obj);
      d.setStyle = fmini.setStyle;
      d.each = fmini.each;
      e.push(d);
    }

    return e;
  },
  setStyle : function(style, value) {
    if (typeof this.style.cssText !== 'undefined') {
      var styleToSet = this.style.cssText;
      if (typeof style === 'object') {
        for (var i in style) 
          if (typeof i === 'string') styleToSet += ';' + i + ':' + style[i];
      }
      else styleToSet += ';' + style + ':' + value;
      this.style.cssText = styleToSet;
    }
    return this;
  },
  each : function (functionCall) {
                for (var i=0, il=this.length; i < il; i++) 
                    functionCall.call(this[i]);
                return this;
    },
}
window.$ = fmini.$;
```

I would like this to work when I do

```
  $('bob','amy').setStyle({
    'border' : '5px solid #ff0000',
    'background-color' : '#ccc'
    });
```

Comment: add some more code formatting in there

Comment: please develop your library in regular, readable JavaScript; after you got it to work, you can always pipe it through a minifier...

Comment: Sorry all! This code is supose to be on multiple lines but stackoverflow isn't agreeing with me! I'm trying to get use to the way you use format code. I have it on multiple lines but its cutting some code off now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your methods to operate on the *set* of nodes returned from `$`. That way both `$('bob').setStyle()` *and* `$('bob', 'amy').setStyle()` will work. I see you have a generic `forEach` or `each` method which is a good start.

```
var fmini = {
    $: function() {
        var i=0, obj;
        var e = [];
        e.setStyle = fmini.setStyle;
        e.each = fmini.each;

        while (obj = arguments[i++]) {
            e.push(document.getElementById(obj));
        }

        return e;
    },

    setStyle : function(style, value) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (typeof this.style.cssText !== 'undefined') {
                var styleToSet = this.style.cssText;
                if (typeof style === 'object') {
                    for (var i in style) 
                        if (typeof i === 'string') styleToSet += ';' + i + ':' + style[i];
                }
                else styleToSet += ';' + style + ':' + value;
                this.style.cssText = styleToSet;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Incidentally this is something `jQuery` was the first to do/popularze.

Comment: -1, $ is still returning an array of functions (in this case), and you cant access them like `$().setStyle`

Comment: @sktrdie: you missed the part where I attached `setStyle` to said array of objects. Please re-read.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this type of augmentation on arrays ([]), sorry about this, and thanks I guess I learned something. Can you augment on pretty much anything?

Comment: @sktrdie: yes you can augment anything. Although the approach in the code sample will work, it is wasteful wrt memory. Memory will be allocated for the extra methods everytime `$` is called. jQuery does it right.

Comment: Thank you crescentfresh! It works perfectly. So if I had lots of '$' calls I would waste lots of extra memory? Is there anyway around this?

Comment: @Gary: Yes. Use a prototype and instantiate it in `$`. The functions don't get copied over to new objects, rather new objects reuse the same functions that are bound to the instantiated objects. Ask another question if you don't know wth I'm talking about (should get lots of help on this topic).

Answer (score 1):

Like you had suspected the return of $ in this case is an array of the elements, you have to extend array with setStyle or add the extension when the array is populated before you pass the array back.  Then you shouldn't get an error saying .setStyle is not a function.  However you will have to also make sure you handle your object context binding when you are chaining like this otherwise `this` is referring to the current scope and not an element in your array.

Answer (score 1):

The $ function is returning an array; it should either be returning the element object itself (d) on which you augment the setStyle method, or just another object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could use my library.

It's called Ally and you can download it here: http://github.com/AllyToolkit/Ally

I noticed you said you want something lightweight, and the stock version of Ally is currently just over 1300 lines, 25KB unminified, and you could easily cut out the parts you don't want.

I wrote it with the intention of being very easy to modify, yet still very powerful, and full of useful features.

I'm releasing the 2nd beta soon tonight. It should be up on the release branch ( http://github.com/AllyToolkit/Ally/tree/release ) within the next hour.

If you decide to try it I hope you enjoy. :)